# Finest topology such that a map is continuous : isn't it the discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ a set and $\mathcal R$ a relation of equivalence of $X$. Set $$q: X\to X/\mathcal R,$$
the natural projection. The [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)), it the finest topology such that $q$ is continuous. Isn't it the discrete topology ? Why do we take the finest instead the thickest (as we usually do) ? For me a set $U\in X/\mathcal R$ is open if $q^{-1}(U)$ is open (and I would say that it's the thickest topology s.t. $q^{-1}(U)$ open...). So why do me defined it as the finest ?

Comment: Take $\mathcal R$ to be the identity relation and see what happens if the codomain is given the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens that, in general, if you endow $X/\mathcal R$ with the discrete topology, then $q$ will *not* be continuous. For instance, if $x\mathrel{\mathcal R}y\iff x=y$, then $q$ will be continuous with respect to the discrete topology on $X/\mathcal R$ if and only if $X$ is a discrete topological space.

Note that if $f$ is a map from $X$ into a topological space $Y$ such that $x\mathrel{\mathcal R}y\implies f(x)=f(y)$ then $f$ induces a map $f^\star\colon X/\mathcal R\longrightarrow Y$. With the topology on $X/\mathcal R$ defined as the finest topology such that $q$ is continuous, then $f^\star$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: So the fact that $q^{-1}(U)$ open is not enough to defined the topology of $X/\mathcal R$ ? If $T$ is a topology on $X/\mathcal R$ s.t. $q:X\to X/\mathcal R$ is continue, but it's not the finest ; would it be a problem ? (because why do we want $f^*$ continue ? btw, what is $f^*$ ?

Comment: The definition of $f^\star$ is: $f^\star([x])=f(x)$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$. I dont understand your first question. The usual way of defining the quotient topology on $X/\mathcal R$ is precisely: $U$ is open if and only if $q^{-1}(U)$ is open. And if the topology on $X/\mathcal R$ was not the finest for which $q$ is continuous, then the property that I mentioned in the second paragraph of my answer would not hold.

Comment: It wouldn't be enough to say that the topology on $X/\mathcal R$ is $$\{U\subset X/\mathcal R\mid q^{-1}(U)\ open \} \ \ ?$$ Why do we need the finer ? Moreover, why do we want that $f^*$ is continuous ? We just want $f$ continuous...

Comment: Yes, it is enough. And that topology is **precisely** the finest topology for which $q$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks you, but why a topology such that $q$ is continue is not enough ? why do we want $q^*$ continuous ? I would say : we defined the open set of $X/R$ as : $U$ is open in $X/R$ if $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. So $q^{-1}(U)$ open implies $U$ open. Moreover, if $U$ is open then by definition $q^{-1}(U)$ is open. Therefore, in any topology where $q$ is continuous we have $U$ open $\iff$ $q^{-1}(U)$ is open... so why do we need the "finest" ? (because as you said : the topology on $X/\mathcal R$ is defined precisely as : $U$ open $\iff$ $q^{-1}(U)$ open.

Comment: And this hold in any topology where $q$ is continuous (by definition)

Comment: If we simply want $q$ to be continuous, then we could just consider on $X/\mathcal R$ the trivial topology. But then the property that I mentioned in the second paragraph of my answer would not hold (not just for $q$ but for a general continuous function from $X$ into a topological space $Y$).

Comment: I just understood ! In fact says : $U$ is open if $q^{-1}(U)$ open exactly mean : $U$ is open $\iff$ $q^{-1}(U)$ open (since the implication is given by the fact that $q$ is continue) and this exactly mean that the topology is the finest such that $q$ continuous (since there is no open $U$ such that $q^{-1}(U)$ is open but not $U$. I just got it. Thank you veeerrryyyyyy much :)

Comment: @Peter If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: done :) $\ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

That would be the case if you were putting a topology on $X$, but in this case you are defining a topology *on the codomain* $X/\mathcal R$ given that $X$ already has one. So the coarsest topology such that $q$ is continuous would be the *in*discrete topology, while in general the discrete topology is too fine because $q^{-1}[A]$ may not be open for all $A\subseteq X/\mathcal R$.

Answer (score 1):

**"Why do we take the finest instead of the thickest topology"**

Intuitively, if you have a map $f:X \to Y,$ where $X$ is a topological space, then the more open sets you have on $Y,$ the less likely it is for $f$ to be continuous (because more inverse images need to be open). Consequently, one wants to find a topology on $Y$ that has as many open sets as possible, but at the same time keeps $f$ continuous (i.e., the finest topology that makes $f$ continuous).